# Gitlab External Https Url is not working anymore

Tags: ssl, openssl, gitlab

I am having a problem with GitLab server external URL
here is what I did :
I changed my GitLab.rb conf
external_url 'https://gitlab.tools.ex.com/'

and here is what I'm using

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.gmail.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "XXXXX"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "ex.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "gitlab@ex.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none' # Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert', see http://api.rubyon$
gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_path'] = "/etc/ssl/certs"
gitlab_rails['smtp_ca_file'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

first problem was a certificate problem :

[ssl problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0bVy.png)

after generating a certificate here is what I'm getting :
[after generating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtm4h.png)

thanks in advance !

Comment: You second image looks like it finished successfully. What's the error you're seeing after setting the certificate?

Comment: i can't acces the url (connection timeout)

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `sudo gitlab-ctl status`? This command will show the current status of all the services Gitlab requires to work properly, such as nginx, sidekiq, redis, etc.